# FTP transfer adds white space to after every line of code

Tags: upload, ftp, newline, whitespace, file-transfer

I use WinSCP for FTP, to upload files on host servers. On some of them, but very rarely, it creates white space after every line of code (new lines in my case). So when I download it back from the server, number of code lines is doubled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that some hosts are using ASCII(text) as default transfer mode, and others use BINARY. So when I change this to the one that server use, there is no more new lines in transfered files.

In WinSCP this is located under **Options->Transfer->Edit->Transfer Mode**